# How can I unpivot multiple columns using jupyter notebook or SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, jupyter-notebook, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table structure in parent-child relationship and I need to unpivot multiple columns with different values.

Here is an example:

[image]

Small example I have put in this table.

**Note:** I have only put few columns here but I have 215 columns in this way and with different Ids and names. So my goal is to flatten out all columns tied with p_id and/or c_id in expected result table.

I am doing this exercise using snowflake. but I am familiar with jupyter notebook as well. Feel free to provide a solution in SQL or using a Python jupyter notebook. You can also suggest any other ways to handle these kind of data.

This image is a part of comment section. Please Check the highlighted part.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by creating a table shaped like the one in the description:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE weird_table
AS 
SELECT 1 AS a, 'b' b, 1 pip1, 2 pip2, 3 pip3, 4 pip4, 11 rip1, 12 rip2, 13 rip3, 14 rip4
UNION ALL SELECT 2 , 'c', 124, 3123, 123, 123, 1231 ,9, 99,999
;

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Now we can create a stored procedure inside Snowflake with JavaScript. Here the script gets the name of a table. Then it takes all the columns that end with a number and uses those to generate different `SELECT` statements, and merges them with a `UNION ALL`:

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE custom_unpivot(TABLE_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
    sqlText: "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " LIMIT 1;",    
});
stmt.execute();

var cols=[];
for (i = 1; i <= stmt.getColumnCount(); i++) {
  cols.push(stmt.getColumnName(i));
}
var idCols = cols.filter(x => !x.match(/[0-9]+$/));
var unpivotCols = cols.filter(x => x.match(/[0-9]+$/));
var maxUnpivot = Math.max(...unpivotCols.map(x => parseInt(x.match(/[0-9]+$/))));
var colsSansSuffix = [...new Set(unpivotCols.map(x => x.replace(/[0-9]+$/, '')))];

selectsToUnion = [];
for (i = 1; i <= maxUnpivot; i++) {
  selectsToUnion.push(
    "SELECT "+idCols+","+colsSansSuffix.map(x=>" "+x+i+" AS "+x)+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME
  );
}
return selectsToUnion.join('\nUNION ALL\n');
$$
;
```

When you call that procedure, it return a combined `SELECT` statement that gives you the desired "unpivot":

```sql
CALL custom_unpivot('weird_table');

SELECT A,B, PIP1 AS PIP, RIP1 AS RIP FROM weird_table
UNION ALL
SELECT A,B, PIP2 AS PIP, RIP2 AS RIP FROM weird_table
UNION ALL
SELECT A,B, PIP3 AS PIP, RIP3 AS RIP FROM weird_table
UNION ALL
SELECT A,B, PIP4 AS PIP, RIP4 AS RIP FROM weird_table
```

If you run that generated SQL, it produces the desired results:

[image]

Once you get how this pattern works within a stored procedure, then the possibilities are endless.

---

For the follow up in the comment, try embedding the resulting query into a filter like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT A,B, PIP1 AS PIP, RIP1 AS RIP FROM A_weird_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT A,B, PIP2 AS PIP, RIP2 AS RIP FROM A_weird_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT A,B, PIP3 AS PIP, RIP3 AS RIP FROM A_weird_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT A,B, PIP4 AS PIP, RIP4 AS RIP FROM A_weird_table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT A,B, PIP5 AS PIP, RIP5 AS RIP FROM A_weird_table
)
WHERE pip>0 AND rip>0;
```

Comment: Hey @Felipe Hoffa,  Does it work with 215 Columns ? I can imagine there will be more unions.

Comment: Yeah, the code generates the unions. Did you try it?

Comment: yes, I was working like a charm! the only problem is **'NULL'** rows. 'Null' rows in the sense of, if all the columns doesn't have any values then it should not return. because I am getting lots of null values data. for example, here   you have data like this where pip 5 is 0 and rip 5 is also 0. 

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE A_weird_table
AS SELECT 1 AS a, 'b' b, 1 pip1, 2 pip2, 3 pip3, 4 pip4,0 pip5, 11 rip1, 12 rip2, 13 rip3, 14 rip4, 0 rip5
UNION ALL SELECT 2 , 'c', 124, 3123, 123, 123,0, 1231 ,9, 99,999,0;

Comment: Cont: 

then it is giving me null  rows which are 1 b and 2 c with 0, I am getting lots of nulls which is increases my table size with in appropriate data. Please provide me a solution how to handle this. 
A,B,PIP,RIP
1,b,1,11
1,b,2,12
1,b,3,13
1,b,4,14
1,b,0,0
2,c,124,1231
2,c,3123,9
2,c,123,99
2,c,123,999
2,c,0,0

I have attached the result image in my question section with your provided data.